# XML Generator, Poco classes

Tags: xml, poco

Is there a XML generator that creates a XML file based on my poco classes? I also want my nested classes in the XML output.

Example:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Xml.Serialization` namespace, with emphasis on the `XmlSerializer` class.